# Visualising GLMM predictions with interaction of categorical and continuous variables

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization, predict, lme4

I am working in R with a GLMM with a mixture of continuous and categorical variables with some interactions. I have used the dredge and model.avg functions in MuMIn to obtain effect estimates for each variable. My problem is in how best to plot the results. I want to make a figure showing the effect of one variable (forest) on my data where the trendline reflects the forest parameter estimate, but I can't figure out how to hold the categorical variables and interaction variables at their 'average' so that the trendline only reflects the effect of forest.

Here's the model and plot set-up:

```
#load packages and document
cuckoo<-read.table("http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~ciaranwi/home_range.txt", 
header=T,sep="\t")
require(lme4)
require(MuMIn)
as.factor (cuckoo$ID)
as.factor (cuckoo$Sex)
as.factor(cuckoo$MS_bin)
options(na.action = "na.fail")

# create global model and fit
fm<- lmer(log(KD_95)~ MS_bin + Forest + NDVI + Sex + Precip + MS_bin*Forest 
+ MS_bin*NDVI  + MS_bin*Sex + MS_bin*Precip + Argos + Sample + (1|ID), data 
= cuckoo, REML = FALSE)

# dredge but always include argos and sample
KD95<-dredge(fm,fixed=c("Argos","Sample"))

# model averaging 
avgmod<-model.avg(KD95, fit=TRUE)
summary(avgmod)

#plot data
plot(cuckoo$Forest, (log(cuckoo$KD_95)),
 xlab = "Mean percentage of forest cover",
 ylab = expression(paste(plain("Log of Kernel density estimate, 95%    
utilisation, km"^{2}))),
 pch = c(15,17)[as.numeric(cuckoo$MS_bin)],  
 main = "Forest cover",
 col="black", 
 ylim=c(14,23))
legend(80,22, c("Breeding","Nonbreeding"), pch=c(15, 17),  cex=0.7)
```

Then I get stuck with how to include a trendline. So far I have:

```
#parameter estimates from model.avg
argos_est<- -1.6
MS_est<- -1.77
samp_est<-0.01
forest_est<--0.02
sex_est<-0.0653
precip_est<-0.0004
ndvi_est<--0.00003
model_intercept<-22.7

#calculate mean values for parameters
argos_mean<-mean(cuckoo$Argos)
samp_mean<-mean(cuckoo$Sample)
forest_mean<-mean(cuckoo$Forest)
ndvi_mean<-mean(cuckoo$NDVI)
precip_mean<-mean(cuckoo$Precip)

#calculate the intercept and add trend line
intercept<-(model_intercept + (forest_est*cuckoo$Forest) +    
(argos_est*argos_mean) + (samp_est * samp_mean) + (ndvi_est*ndvi_mean) +  
(precip_est*precip_mean) )

abline(intercept, forest_est)
```

But this doesn't consider the interactions or the categorical variables and the intercept looks way too high. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need to create a new object for each parameter (`argos_est <- -1.6`, etc.). You can just do `coef(avgmod)` and that will give you all the coefficients.

Comment: thanks! definitely a tidier way of getting the estimates...but I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of process, you can make your coding much easier by taking advantage of the fact that R stores lots of information about the model in the model object and has functions to get information out of the model object. For example, `coef(avgmod)` will give you the model coefficients and `predict(avgmod)` will give you the model's predictions for each observation in the data frame you used to fit the model.

To visualize predictions for specific combinations of data values we're interested in, create a new data frame that has the means of the variables we want to hold constant, along with a range of values for variables that we want to vary (like `Forest`). `expand.grid` creates a data frame with all combinations of the values listed below.

```
pred.data = expand.grid(Argos=mean(cuckoo$Argos), Sample=mean(cuckoo$Sample), 
                        Precip=mean(cuckoo$Precip), NDVI=mean(cuckoo$NDVI), 
                        Sex="M", Forest=seq(0,100,10), MS_bin=unique(cuckoo$MS_bin), 
                        ID=unique(cuckoo$ID))
```

Now we use the `predict` function to add predictions for log(KD_95) to this data frame. `predict` takes care of calculating the model predictions for whatever data you feed it (assuming you give it a data frame that includes all the variables in your model).

```
pred.data$lgKD_95_pred = predict(avgmod, newdata=pred.data)
```

Now we plot the results. `geom_point` plots the points, as in your original plot, then `geom_line` adds the predictions for each level of `MS_bin` (and Sex="M").

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=cuckoo, aes(Forest, log(KD_95), shape=factor(MS_bin), 
             colour=factor(MS_bin), size=3)) +
  geom_line(data=pred.data, aes(Forest, lKD_95_pred, colour=factor(MS_bin)))
```

Here's the result:

[image]

**UPDATE:** To plot regression lines for both male and female, just include Sex="F" in `pred.data` and add `Sex` as an aesthetic in the plot. In the example below, I use different shapes to mark `Sex` when plotting the points and different line types to mark `Sex` for the regression lines.

```
pred.data = expand.grid(Argos=mean(cuckoo$Argos), Sample=mean(cuckoo$Sample), 
                        Precip=mean(cuckoo$Precip), NDVI=mean(cuckoo$NDVI), 
                        Sex=unique(cuckoo$Sex), Forest=seq(0,100,10), MS_bin=unique(cuckoo$MS_bin), 
                        ID=unique(cuckoo$ID))

pred.data$lgKD_95_pred = predict(avgmod, newdata=pred.data)

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=cuckoo, aes(Forest, log(KD_95), shape=Sex, 
                              colour=factor(MS_bin)), size=3) +
  geom_line(data=pred.data, aes(Forest, lgKD_95_pred, linetype=Sex, 
                                colour=factor(MS_bin)))
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to do something similar with the "predict" function, but I tried to "fix" MS_bin as well and then I got confused with the mention "...hold the categorical variables and interaction variables at their 'average'". I think it's tricky, as you can hold the categorical variables to their mode (most common observation) and you'll always lose some info.

Comment: You can also convert binary predictors to 0/1 numeric variables to fit the model and then use the mean (the proportion of cases with value=1) for prediction. The predictions won't apply to any specific case, but they will give you the regression line for the "average" case.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You can also substitute the binary values with the percentage of the "success" case (extra process, so maybe the 1/0 trick is faster), but what about categorical variables that are not binary? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: The [`effects`](http://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/6305045.pdf) and [`visreg`](http://myweb.uiowa.edu/pbreheny/publications/visreg.pdf) packages have some nice visualizations for categorical predictors. I also often use the various aesthetics and faceting in `ggplot` to look at various combinations of categorical predictors.

Comment: eipi - this helps a lot! Thank you. What I am still a little unclear on is how I can include the interactions in this same framework? Also, the trendlines are for the two levels of MS_bin right? But does that only reflect the data for Sex=M? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, the lines are for the two levels of MS_bin with Sex="M". See my update for how to add lines for both sexes. Regarding interactions, you're already seeing one in the graphs above. You have an interaction between MS_bin and Forest, which is why the slopes of the blue and red lines are different. If you re-run your model without the `MS_bin*Forest` term, then those lines will be parallel when you plot them.

Comment: To plot interactions involving two continuous variables, you can pick, say, two quantiles for each variable when you construct your `pred.data` data frame and then plot different lines for each of the four combinations of values for those two variables.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I am not missing the point, but if you want a linear trend you don't actually have to manually calculate everything, but get what you plotted and fit a y~x linear regression model, like this:

```
model = lm(log(cuckoo$KD_95)~cuckoo$Forest)

model

# Call:
#   lm(formula = log(cuckoo$KD_95) ~ cuckoo$Forest)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)  cuckoo$Forest  
#      17.13698       -0.01461 

abline(17.13698 ,  -0.01461, col="red")
```

[image]

The red line is using the intercept and slope from the regression fit. Black line is your manual process.

Comment: Hi Antonio, thanks for your suggestion. The regression line is how I started out making this figure, but I was hoping to switch the line to reflect the actual parameter estimates from the model, rather than using a different methodology for the figure and the actual model.

Comment: Based on @elpi 's comment, which is the best way to get the estimates, can you make sure you have the correct values for your estimates?

Comment: elpi is right that the coef(avgmod) is a much neater way of getting the estimates, but they are still the same values, so I still have the same question.

Comment: I think you have to give some thought about how you expect your output/plot to be. You have a model in a N-dimensional space and you want to project it in a 2-dimensional space (your plot) by holding rest of variables to their means. How do you imagine the interaction of two fixed values? I have a feeling that what you're trying to observe/visualise is a model/plot between log(KD_95) and Forest.