# Simple R Plot Growth curve

Tags: r, ggplot2, lme4

I am hoping to plot a fairly simple Growth Curve Model in R. My code is below

```
m <- lmer(height ~ age * SES + FEMALE+(1 + age | ID), data=df1, REML=F)
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loq34.png) is a plot I am hoping to make with JUST the lines and error bands--not the individual data points. I am hoping to have one line for MALE and one line for FEMALE on the same plot. Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at the `plot_model` function in the `sjPlot` package, it might be useful.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32402457/2461552) shows the general "by hand" approach.  That answer involves model averaging, though, so you will instead likely want to use `re.form = NA` when making the predictions.  For CI, see [this link](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#lme4)